# screen lock - CodeIgniter

Tags: php

Hi I am a beginner in codeigniter and I have a question, how to make a screen lock that will turn off after some action such as pressing a button / entering a code. The lock is to be based on the fact that until we do something will appear to us a page that can not be bypassed.
[in the link an example from modesy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7ikh.png)

Thank you for any help

Comment: If something is not clear, feel free to discuss

Comment: make a route /locked and redirect there if "something happens"

Comment: not stupid, but would it be possible to combine it with e.g. the installer ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, not clear enough. redirect to /installer then

Comment: I'm sorry I explained it wrong. I want to do something like the installer for the aforementioned modesy i.e. If the files have never been installed it shows "Modesy 1.8 install" which cannot be bypassed.

Comment: something like an overlay in CI

Comment: Its same logic as Login, if(some == condition) redirect to login else dashboard. You can save some condition in sessions and if that is not defined redirect to installer

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, have a good night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a session variable `locked`

```
$this->session->set_userdata('locked', false);


if(Something == true) {

   $this->session->set_userdata('locked', true);
}
```

Then check if has to be locked:

```
if($this->session->userdata('locked')){

redirect_to "/install"

}
```

then after finishing install
 `$this->session->set_userdata('locked', false);`